# Is rxjava2 overprotected on thread safety?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, rx-java2

I have been using RxJava2 for a long time.
Recently, I am studying RxJava2 from its source codes, trying to understand it, writing my own operator implementation.
I found there are many codes for thread safety. But I think some are superfluous, which increases the difficulty when learning.

According to [Reactive Streams specs](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.2/README.md) 2.7 "A Subscriber MUST ensure that all calls on its Subscription take place from the same thread or provide for respective external synchronization.".
Isn't it that it's caller's duty to make sure its calls are thread-safe?

But I found  "io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableLimit$LimitSubscriber.request" this method uses AtomicLong to achive atomicity. And many other codes do so. Why?

Answer (score 1):

> But I think some are superfluous, which increases the difficulty when learning.

When implementing operators, one has to consider a lot of possible concurrent interactions along the various signal types coming from different sources/consumers. I spent a lot of time working out and optimizing RxJava 2. Concurrency is hard and I'm pretty sure there are practically no "superfluous" implementation details. There is always a reason why some algorithms look the way they are. However, there could be a few optimization possibilities but those have to be carefully analyzed and thought about.

> According to Reactive Streams specs 2.7

There [have been](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/issues/405) and [are currently](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/issues/431) some discussions and refinements about the wording of the rules given how practical implementations such as RxJava and Project Reactor turned out.

> Isn't it that it's caller's duty to make sure its calls are thread-safe?

The `Publisher` of a particular operator is usually in the best position to ensure thread safety when calling `Subscriber.onXXX` methods. Otherwise a `Subscriber` would need to know much more about what its source is or does.

> But I found "io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableLimit$LimitSubscriber.request"

There are many ways to ensure thread safety. The wording "synchronization" doesn't necessarily mean the Java keyword `synchronized` has to be used. RxJava predominantly uses so-called lock-free algorithms that leverage atomic operations provided by the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` classes. Request management is typically such a "client" for lock-free atomics.

Answer (score 0):

The Subscription Oject from the API you are using "RXJava2" is not Thread safe from itself, but you have to make it Thread safe if you are using RXJava2. or just use a single thread.

```
"A Subscriber MUST ensure that all calls on its Subscription are thread Safe"
```

Its basically a warning saying with multiple threads weird situations might occur and you should really think about the consequences when multiple thread come across a piece of code written with the "Subscribtion" class.

The but question I can't answer as it might be some people started to change the code and tried to make it more thread safe (bit by bit ) Code evolves and changes, and it warns in the documentation about the pieces which are not yet thread safe.

Hopefully this helps.